# Global Data in ASP MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a site for our poker league. In the _Layout page I would like to include some database information like the next game date and how many games of the season are remaining. I presume _Layout is the best page as I would like this information on ALL pages.

How can I get this entity framework data there? I presume a controller is not the way as _Layout is only a template for other views that use their own controllers.

Any information or resources would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Paul.

Comment: You can render a partial view.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a base controller from which all your controllers inherit.
There you can overwrite the method `OnActionExecuting()` and load that data from the DB, the cache or whereever and pass it to the Viewbag:

```
public class ControllerBase {
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx) {
      Viewbag.LayoutPageData = ...;
  }
}
```

Or you can use a base class for all your Viewmodels and pass the data with the model to the view.

Your Layout page is a view also, so you can strongly type it with a viewmodel class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Html.Action like in this sample

http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/viewdata-or-viewbag-avoid-dependency-pollution-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

you can display your database information  in a partial page exemple "_NextGameDate.cshtml"

then you have to include it in _Layout.cshtml page by :

```
 @Html.Partial("_NextGameDate.cshtml");
```